# Performing several FTP requests at the same time

Tags: c#, ftp, backgroundworker

I have a list of FTP remote files, and I'm trying to retrieve the file sizes for each and every of them. The files are on different servers.

I have a method `GetFileSize`, which is working very well. Currently I'm processing the list each item at a time, with a simple loop.

Considering that a simple request for the file size won't take up much bandwidth, I'd like to perform all the requests at the same time, asynchronously.

I have tried using a array of `BackgroundWorker`s for each item, but the result is that only the last item in the list is being processed:

```
public static void GetFileSizes(List<string> files)
{
    BackgroundWorker[] workers = new BackgroundWorker[files.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        workers[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
        workers[i].WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        workers[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        workers[i].DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            long size = Ftp.GetSize(files[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());
        };
        workers[i].RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: First comment is that background threads typically do not display any data.  To do that you can and should use a semiphore with WorkerReportsProgress True.  The thread that get's the progress handles each report synchronously, and will not need to marshall onto gui thread.  I am guessing what is happening is that you are only seeing the last message because until that background thread completes it will not marshall the messagebox onto GUI thread.

Comment: @JohnPeters Setting WorkerReportsProgress to true didn't change anything, what I've noticed though, is that when I set the runtime condition of the for-loop to "i < files.Count", as it should be, it will throw a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException as somehow the i got to 2. How can this be explained? The List<string> files contains only 2 entries, and thus the value of i should never rise above 1.

Comment: Just setting it to true won't do anything, you also have to log information on each thread iteration! This is done in the DoWork method.  Look up what this value does on MSDN...

Comment: There's no reason to be doing IO bound work in background threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are failing to ensure that each anonymous method captures a different variable. The `for` loop variable `i` is the same variable for each anonymous method.

Since the current thread is doing so little, the probability of it completing the entire loop before either worker gets to run at all is extremely high. When this happens, the variable `i` is at the first value that doesn't fulfill the loop condition, i.e. `file.Count - 1`.

When you write the loop conventionally, the variable's value at the end of the loop is `file.Count`, hence the exception.

There are a variety of ways to fix this, but IMHO the best and easiest is to capture the *file name* instead of the index. This not only addresses your immediate concern, but isolates the workers from the actual `files` object so that if you have a bug elsewhere and modify that object before the workers are done, it won't affect the workers.

E.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string file = files[i];

    workers[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
    workers[i].WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    workers[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    workers[i].DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    {
        long size = Ftp.GetSize(file);
        MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());
    };
    workers[i].RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Finally, don't set the `WorkerReportsProgress` or the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` properties to `true` unless you actually *implement* the respective behavior in your worker.

(And I assume that in your real code, you won't be calling `MessageBox.Show()` from the worker thread...that's a bad idea too, at least for non-debugging scenarios).